# AWS S3 v2 GetObject Unable to unmarshall response (java.net.SocketTimeoutException)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I'm trying to get a large object from S3 and steam the output straight to an HttpServletResponse output stream.

However it always fails on this object due to a `SocketTimeoutException`.

Here's the code that uses the S3Client to get the object:

```
    public void downloadMergedResults(final String jobId, final OutputStream os) {
        get("jobs/" + jobId + "/results", os);
    }

    private boolean get(final String key, final OutputStream outputStream) {
        log.trace("GET {}", key);
        try {
            client.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build(), ResponseTransformer.toOutputStream(outputStream));
            return true;
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            if (e.statusCode() == 404) {
                log.info("Item with key: {} does not exist.", key);
            }
            else {
                log.error("Could not get item {} from S3. Error: {} {}", key, e.getMessage(), e.awsErrorDetails());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here's how I'm using that within my springboot application:

```
    public Callable<ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>> allData(HttpServletResponse res, @PathVariable("jobId") String jobId) {

        Progress progress = s3client.downloadCachedProgress(jobId);
        if (progress == null) {
            log.info("{} Could not find progress file", jobId);
            return () -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        res.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        res.setContentLengthLong(OPEN_ARRAY.length + progress.getDataSizeBytes() + (SEPARATOR.length * (progress.getMediaCount() - 1)) + CLOSE_ARRAY.length);

        return () -> {
            StreamingResponseBody streamingResponseBody = out -> {
                try {
                    s3client.downloadMergedResults(jobId, out);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    log.error("{} Error downloading results: {}", jobId, e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            };
            return new ResponseEntity<>(streamingResponseBody, HttpStatus.OK);
        };
    }
```

This is what curl says:

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with 524076376 bytes remaining to read
```

This is the stack trace from my app:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (java.net.SocketTimeoutException). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:98) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleSuccessResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:108) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:72) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:59) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:40) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:64) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:34) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:189) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:121) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:147) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:52) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:62) ~[aws-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.getObject(DefaultS3Client.java:3539) ~[s3-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at org.me.blobstorage.S3ClientWrapper.get(S3ClientWrapper.java:362) ~[classes!/:na]
        at org.me.blobstorage.S3ClientWrapper.downloadMergedResults(S3ClientWrapper.java:253) ~[classes!/:na]
        at org.me.RequestHandler.lambda$null$4(RequestHandler.java:241) ~[classes!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:111) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:98) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$4(WebAsyncManager.java:328) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.NonRetryableException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.NonRetryableException$BuilderImpl.build(NonRetryableException.java:92) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler$HttpResponseHandlerAdapter.transformResponse(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:187) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler$HttpResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:168) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleSuccessResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:97) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:364) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils.copy(IoUtils.java:113) ~[utils-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils.copy(IoUtils.java:99) ~[utils-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.ResponseTransformer.lambda$toOutputStream$2(ResponseTransformer.java:159) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler$HttpResponseHandlerAdapter.transformResponse(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:180) ~[sdk-core-2.13.44.jar!/:na]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:134) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:584) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:522) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:538) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:73) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:601) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:339) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Here are the different ways I've tried initialising my S3Client:

1:

```
        client = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
```

2:

```
        client = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .overrideConfiguration(ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                        .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofHours(1))
                        .build())
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
```

3:

```
        client = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .overrideConfiguration(ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                        .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofHours(1))
                        .build())
                .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder()
                        .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofHours(1))
                        .socketTimeout(Duration.ofHours(1)).build())
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
```

4:

```
        client = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .overrideConfiguration(ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                        .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofHours(1))
                        .build())
                .httpClientBuilder(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder()
                        .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofHours(1))
                        .socketTimeout(Duration.ofHours(1)))
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
```

My spring boot applications.properties setting for request timeouts:

```
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=-1
```

and I have `@EnableAsync` on my bootstrap class.

The requests are proxied through nginx, with the settings on the location as:

```
upstream myupstream {
  server [SERVER-REDACTED]:[PORT-REDACTED];
  keepalive 15;
}


server {
...
  location ~ ^/(v1/bigsearch|actuator)/ {
    proxy_pass http://myupstream;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    client_max_body_size 2G;
  }
...
}
```

And the relevant nginx.conf entries itself:

```
http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 1d;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    proxy_read_timeout 1d;
    proxy_send_timeout 1d;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

## Question

What haven't I done to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, I struggle with a problem for days, post it on SO and then figure it out.

Even though the error manifests as a SocketTimeoutException, the problem actually lies with nginx proxy buffering.

After a while it struck me as important the download always topped out at 1G, and it wasn't until I searched for that specifically that I discovered the actual problem and solution here: https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/5706

Adding these settings into the nginx.conf file resolved it:

```
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_buffering off;
```